# Detection of too many tiny areas when measuring large particles in binary images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, watershed

I am moving from ImageJ to Python for doing image processing of images showing particles - either on a bench or falling - and trying to write my first code for 1) opening images of particles, 2) applying thresholding and noise reduction to obtain binary images, 3) apply watershed to separate overlapping particles, and 4) measure the detected regions to get information on particle size distributions (e.g., area, perimeter, axes).

I am working on the attached image for now, to keep things simple. It's a bunch of particles from 0.5 to 1 mm in diameter on a bench.

[Particles 0.5-1 mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvbon.jpg)

Now, I wrote this code in Python that uses a mix of opencv and skimage functions to create and polish binary images, apply watershed (Not needed for the example above, but for the future - where I will image falling particles at high-speed - it'll be very useful), and measure the identified cells.

Edit: attached a second image where I have the same issue, but for smaller particles (0.250-0.5 mm, but where watershed is important)'

[Smaller particles where I need watershed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHp04.jpg)

EDIT2: Shorter code to show the main processing leading to the issue.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from skimage.segmentation import watershed, clear_border
from skimage import measure, color, io, morphology

# Define the folder path containing the images
image = "C:/..."

# Set scale pixels/mm (either based on ImageJ or by reference image, or calculations)
px_per_mm = 222
mm_per_px = 1 / px_per_mm
img = cv2.imread(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Threshold and remove noise
thresholded_img =  cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = np.ones((5, 5),np.uint8)
image = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded_img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
image = clear_border(image)

# Prepare for Watershed
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(image,kernel, iterations=4)
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(image, cv2.DIST_L2, 0)
ret2, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.4 * dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)
ret3, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg, connectivity=8)
markers = markers + 10
markers[unknown == 255] = 0

# Now we are ready for watershed filling.
markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)

#Measure properties
label_image = measure.label(markers,background=255, connectivity=None)
props = measure.regionprops_table(label_image, image,
                          properties=['label', 'Area'])

# Scale properties from pixels to mm
props['Area'] = props['Area'] * mm_per_px ** 2

# Remove the image frame that is usually identified as a region
max_area_threshold = 700
props_df = pd.DataFrame(props)
filtered_props = props_df[props_df['Area'] <= max_area_threshold]
# Convert the filtered properties to a DataFrame
particle_analysis = pd.DataFrame(filtered_props)
```

Now, the current code gives me this distribution for the particles area:

[Area distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOqz9.png)

It is mostly correct, but showing a lot of areas in the 0.0-0.5 bin, that are not present in the image once the noise and the small particulate is eliminated.
With ImageJ, I would get similar results but without the huge initial bin:
[ImageJ results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OaXC.png)

If I check the binary image, watershed etc, it all seem fine, so no idea why is detecting such small regions. It happens with all the images I am using for testing the code.

Any help in identifying the issue is most welcome! Many thanks!

I wrote the code based on tutorials on opencv and skimage, and tested several ways of thresholding, reducing noise, morphology operations and changing parameters of the functions for measuring the regions, trying to only detect the real particles in the analysis. However, I always get that initial bin with apparently regions characterized by very small areas

Comment: Have you filtered out all the tiny particles. You should get the contours and filter on area. Or use morphology to remove the small regions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @fmw42: yes, I filter out the tiny particles with morphology operationa. I did some testing modifying how much I remove, but I always get the same issue

Comment: @ Cris Luengo: apologies., you are right. I removed the whole code and left only the main processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```py
image = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded_img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

removes small objects, and smooths out the boundary of larger objects. But the objects being removed are smaller than a 5x5 pixel square, which is 0.0005 mm². The ImageJ code you're replicating somehow filters out much larger particles. When I look at the size distribution for the particles smaller than 0.1 mm², I see something that likely is drawn from a log-normal distribution, with particles in the range 0.006-0.015. So you could remove all particles smaller than, say 0.02 mm² (~31x31 pixels).

You can accomplish that in two ways:

1. Use a much larger structuring element in the opening. This is problematic because OpenCV is very slow with larger structuring elements, and because a larger opening will distort the area of larger objects. If you go this route, you should use a circular structuring element, not a square one.*
2. Filter out smaller particles afterwards, like you do with larger objects. Just add a minimum area threshold to this line:

```py
filtered_props = props_df[props_df['Area'] <= max_area_threshold]
```

There's a third option, which is that these smaller particles are actually part of your sample and you *should* be measuring them...

---

<sup>* I would also suggest you use [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) instead of OpenCV, it's opening is much faster with larger structuring elements. But I'm biased because I'm quite deeply involved in that project.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Initially I did think about  filtering out the smaller objects as well. But I was getting weird results. Then, by adding the filtering within the same line "filtered_props = props_df[(props_df['Area'] >= min_area_threshold) & (props_df['Area'] <= max_area_threshold)].copy()", rather than two different lines, it seems to work. Your third option I can understand it, but in these cases the smaller particles are the results of impacts, friction due to transport etc. These are controlled size distributions, so it should be well constrained.